# How to permanently alter a js array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, object

So I have a object array I am using to store data for my app. It's in a store file, using mobx. How come when I write some code to alter or add to a object in the array, that data is deleted upon a refresh?

Is there anyway to permanently alter the object so it persists through different sessions? (trying to avoid using a database, using the object as my database).

Here's a sample of the data

```
Bars: [
    {
      Name: "Bull and Finch Neighborhood Pub",
      Address: "11520 24 St SE",
      Latitude: 50.95231,
      Longitude: -114.00132,
      Reviews: [],
      Likes: 0,
      Specials: [
        {
          Monday: [
            { Desc: "Burgers", Price: "50% Off", Cat: "Burgers" },
            { Desc: "Coors Banquet Pints", Price: 5.5, Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Tuesday: [
            { Desc: "Pizza and a Jug", Price: 26, Cat: "Pizza" },
            { Desc: "Draft Jugs", Price: "2$ Off", Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Wednesday: [
            { Desc: "Wings", Price: 0.45, Cat: "Wings" },
            { Desc: "Import Draught", Price: "1$ Off", Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Thursday: [
            { Desc: "Steak Sandwich", Price: 7.99, Cat: "Sandwiches" },
            { Desc: "Desserts", Price: "50% Off", Cat: "Dessert" },
            { Desc: "Bottles of Wine", Price: "50% Off", Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Friday: [
            { Desc: "Entrees", Price: "2$ Off", Cat: "Entrees" },
            { Desc: "Original 16 Pints", Price: 5.5, Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Saturday: [
            { Desc: "Boneless Wings", Price: 7.95, Cat: "Wings" },
            { Desc: "Specialty Drinks", Price: "1$ Off", Cat: "Drinks" }
          ],
          Sunday: [
            { Desc: "BBQ Brisket", Price: 14.99, Cat: "Entrees" },
            { Desc: "Ribs", Price: 0.45, Cat: "Entrees" },
            { Desc: "Jack Daniels", Price: 5.25, Cat: "Drinks" }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Don't confuse an Object with localStorage.

Comment: Store it in a cookie or localStorage

Answer (score 1):

Simply put your data needs to be persisted and reloaded upon each request either using a database or local storage.

Comment: forgot about local storage, but that wouldn't sync across multiple users right? This is trying to be a small website, so data like reviews or likes would need to show to anyone viewing it

Comment: Try PouchDb it seriously rocks.

Comment: Will do, that looks perfect for what I'm trying to do, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the best way forward for you would be to use Node.js to write to file, and save your object to file. Then later read from file.

Take a look at the fs API for how to do that.

https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: that sounds very doable, that would allow multiple users to be synced to the same data as long as I'm writing and reading correctly right?

Comment: Sure. You would just need to give those multiple users read permissions to that file.
Or... you could not secure that data at all, and just leave it out for anyone to read off your AWS bucket, as seems fashionable these days in massive data leaks with people's private information.